# To add Voting Option in Microsoft Graph API using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on use case where I need to send an outlook mail with voting options like approve or reject. I have seen few threads but they are of different languages and the usage very much different from python module. I have seen Microsoft Graph API Documentation but couldn't find a proper implementation. Can anyone of you please provide a a way on how this can be done via python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Graph exposes voting options. On the Extended MAPI level, the voting options are stored in the `VerbStream` named MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/85200102"`). In theory, you can construct that binary property - its format is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxomsg/87488eff-3eec-4502-bc94-2368c04e3109) by Microsoft, and you can set it on a message.

```
"singleValueExtendedProperties":[{"id":"Binary {00062008-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8520","value":"AgEIA....vAA=="}]
```

If you don't want to dynamically build that property, you can just hardcode its binary value in your code from an existing Outlook message that has the right value.

You can see its value on a Graph message in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select a message with the voting options set, click Message button on the Graph group on OutlookSpy ribbon. Click "Query Parameters..." button, then button next to the $expand edit box, select the VerbStream property, click OK, make sure $expand is checked, click "Run Query".

[image]

You can also see the parsed value of that property in the IMessage window:

[image]